# jQuery UI Slider overlap slidebar

Tags: jquery, css

I use a slider range (jquery ui) and a side navigation bar (w3 school).

The handler of the slider range overlap the side navigation bar when it extend.

css of the side bar:

```
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SIDENAV ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

No Overlap: When the handler is not in the same plan as the navigation bar
[image]

Overlap: When the handler is in the same plan as the navigation bar
[image]

What can be the cause of this overlapping?

Comment: Could you show your html as well?

Comment: try increasing 'z-index' of your sidebar.

Comment: Put the smallest example of working code in place so we can see it in action rather than just images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was given in the comment section.

The solution is to raise the z-index of the sidebar.

```
.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 10;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #111;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
padding-top: 60px;
```

}

As the sidebar should always be on top, maybe rise it to a high value to never have this problem.